# How to hit OK button after opening an EXE through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

So I have a batch file which I use to run a few modules(basically some EXEs). But for some some of them, I need to hit 'OK' after the modules are opened. Is there any way I can do it from the batch file itself?

Comment: hit OK ? you mean the EXE has UI and need to click a button ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes the exe opens an UI and the 1st step is to hit the OK button. Is there any way I can do it from the batch file itself?

Comment: You should look at `AutoIt`.

Comment: or any other mouse macro software.

Answer (score 0):

It it just needs an enter keypress then try this:

```
 echo.|file.exe
```